# how can I align a line a vertices evenly preserving the angle?

Tags: vertices

I would like to know how I can align a group of vertices at an angle without having to resort to scaling to zero on an axis. in the picture below how would you make it the vertices circled in green line up the same angle the end points? I know I could just dissolve them and add them again but that would require reconnecting everything again.

[image]

Comment: you may find a lot of answers on this topic: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=align+vertices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I found the correct answer from another user named Denis. turns out the looptool>gstretch was the answer. I always ignored it since the description said it's for grease pencil strokes but does exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

in situations like **this** You could use the "Relax" function from the "LoopTools" as shown on the image below.

[image]

It will correct the line even if the inside verticies are moved vertically. LoopTools could be *activated in Preferences/Addons* section. Sometimes You need to use the function more than once to get a desired result so for speed things up select more Iterations (10, 25). Hope it helps buddy.

Sincerely, Jan

Comment: If you are using loop tools why not use Gstreatch? Without Grease Pencil strokes it only straightens whatever is selected.

Comment: Yes, this could be used if You do not use the Grease in fact but I dunno if it also make them even vertically as Relax...